# Trying to create an Azure logic app connection but I got error

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm trying to create a work, recieve a message from SAP.

I build a VM and install latist SAP NCo (SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.0.23.0 for Windows 64bit (x64), May 28, 2020), SAP Logon 760 and on-permises data gateways.

when I trying to create the connection, I got a error report here:

Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: Failed to process request. Error details: 'Could not load file or assembly 'sapnco, Version=3.0.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50436dca5c7f7d23' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What should I do? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD7Gu.png)

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, it seems the assembly files might be in the wrong location. So please check and make sure that you copied the assembly files to the data gateway installation folder. You can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-sap-connector#prerequisites).

[image]